# Getting checked values from treeview checkbox using jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, treeview

I am using jquery plugin highchecktree by taking reference from

[of this site sample json with ui](http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/jQuery-Plugin-To-Create-Checkbox-Tree-View-highchecktree.html)

Getting checked values.It works well but they didn't mention how to get the checked values from the treeview checkbox plugin.can anybody solve this.how to get the values only checked valuesfrom  the treeview checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is for parent
mockData[0].item.checked
this is for children
mockData[0].children[0].item.checked

Answer (score 0):

This function will return all id's of checked items array.

```
var mockData = [];
mockData.push({
  item:{
    id: 'id1',
    label: 'label1',
    checked: false
  },
  children: [{
     item:{
      id: 'id11',
      label: 'label11',
      checked: false
    } 
  },{
     item:{
      id: 'id12',
      label: 'label12',
      checked: false
    } 
  },{
     item:{
      id: 'id13',
      label: 'label13',
      checked: false
    } 
  }]
});

mockData.push({
  item:{
    id: 'id2',
    label: 'label2',
    checked: false
  },
  children: [{
     item:{
      id: 'id21',
      label: 'label21',
      checked: false
    } 
  },{
     item:{
      id: 'id22',
      label: 'label22',
      checked: true
    } 
  },{
     item:{
      id: 'id23',
      label: 'label23',
      checked: false
    } 
  }]
});

mockData.push({
  item:{
    id: 'id3',
    label: 'label3',
    checked: false
  },
  children: [{
     item:{
      id: 'id31',
      label: 'label31',
      checked: true
    } 
  },{
     item:{
      id: 'id32',
      label: 'label32',
      checked: false
    },
    children: [{
      item:{
        id: 'id321',
        label: 'label321',
        checked: false
      }
    },{
      item:{
        id: 'id322',
        label: 'label322',
        checked: false
      }
    }]
  }]
});


    function getCheckedItems() {
        var checkedItem = [];
        $.each(mockData, function( index, value ) {
            var id = mockData[index].item.id;
            if(mockData[index].item.checked){
                checkedItem.push(id);
            }
        });
        return checkedItem;
    }
```